# EF Core dynamic include and order

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I'm trying to include related entities and order them as well.

If you know the entity and related items it can be as simple as:

```
context.Set<Item>().Include(x => x.SubItems.OrderBy(x => x.Name));
```

Now I'm trying to replicate the above scenario dynamically, which should turn out something like:

```
{[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryRootExpression].Include(x => x.SubItems.OrderBy(y => y.Name))}
```

But instead the closest I got is this:

```
{[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryRootExpression].Include(x => x.SubItems).OrderBy(y => y.Name)}
```

What am I doing wrong here? here is my code:

```
    private static IQueryable<T> IncludeNaviagations<T>(DbContext context, IQueryable<T> queryable)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);

        foreach (var nav in context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).GetNavigations())
        {                
            var method = IncludeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { type, type.GetProperty(nav.Name).PropertyType });

            var includeParam = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
            var includeProperty = Expression.Property(includeParam, nav.Name);
            var includeLambda =  Expression.Lambda(includeProperty, includeParam);

            var include = Expression.Call(instance: null, method: IncludeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(type, nav.PropertyInfo.PropertyType), arguments: new[] { queryable.Expression, Expression.Quote(includeLambda) });

            var orderColumn = "Name";

            var property = type.GetProperty(orderColumn);
            var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "y");
            var propName = Expression.Property(param, orderColumn);
            var sort = Expression.Lambda(propName, param);

            var result = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy", new[] { type, sort.ReturnType }, include, Expression.Quote(sort));

            queryable = queryable.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(result);
        }

        return queryable;
    }
```

PS. the method above will be tweaked a bit to do the includes recursively.

Comment: As far as I am aware, you can not order an include like that as it is not supported.  If you need the children sorted, there is probably a better way, like ordering them in your view, projection, or view model.

Comment: @RobertMcKee include and order feature was added in ef core 5.0.

Comment: You are correct, they did add them in ef-core 5.0.  In that case, the OrderBy should be part of the includeLamda expression, I would think.   I'm not an expert, but that would appear to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending quite a bit of time on this, I got it working, here is a pieced together solution:

```
OrderByMethodInfo = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "OrderBy" && x.GetParameters().Length == 2);
    
var orderColumnType = subType.GetProperty(orderColumn).PropertyType;

orderByMethod = orderByMethod.MakeGenericMethod(subType, orderColumnType);

var includeParam = Expression.Parameter(nav.ParentType, "x");
var includeProperty = Expression.Property(includeParam, nav.Name);

var property = nav.ParentType.GetProperty(orderColumn);
var param = Expression.Parameter(subType, "y");
var propName = Expression.Property(param, orderColumn);
var sort = Expression.Lambda(propName, param);

var order = Expression.Call(orderByMethod, includeProperty, sort);
var orderLambda = Expression.Lambda(order, Expression.Parameter(nav.ParentType, "x"));
var orderQuote = Expression.Quote(orderLambda);

var includeMethod = IncludeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(nav.ParentType, typeof(IOrderedEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(subType));

result = Expression.Call(instance: null, method: includeMethod, arguments: new[] { queryable.Expression, orderQuote });

queryable.Provider.CreateQuery<object>(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Noobercong.DynamicInclude](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NooberCong.DynamicInclude/) package

The expression for your example is

```
context.Set<Item>().DynamicInclude("SubItems<Name>");
```